# How to Transpose Column Values to Row Values in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, transpose

I want to do the Market Basket Analysis in R and Need my Python data to be transformed before that.

Current Data:

```
[[Value1, Value2, Value3,...],
[Value3, Value4, Value5,...],
[Value4, Value2, Value1,...]]
```

### Expected Output

```
User1 Value1
User1 Value2
User1 Value3
User2 Value3
User2 Value4
User2 Value5
User3 Value4
User3 Value2
User3 Value1
```

Comment: where `User` exists? Post your attempts..

Comment: No user is represented by each of the list. For ex. Value1, Value2, Value3 belongs to user1. and so on.

Comment: Have you actually written any code, or are you just expecting someone to do it for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Value list (nested lists, not really rows and columns)

```
In [264]: ll=[[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[4,2,1]]
```

User name list - one value per item in `ll`:

```
In [265]: ul=['user1','user2','user3']
```

A flattened output combining values from `ul` and `ll`

```
In [266]: print('\n'.join(['%s %s'%(i,x) for i,j in zip(ul,ll) for x in j]))
user1 1
user1 2
user1 3
user2 3
user2 4
user2 5
user3 4
user3 2
user3 1
```

Obviously this could be cast as nest `for`, with line print.  Or left as list of strings or list of tuples (or sublists):

```
In [268]: ['%s %s'%(i,x) for i,j in zip(ul,ll) for x in j]
Out[268]: 
['user1 1',
 'user1 2',
 'user1 3',
 'user2 3',
 'user2 4',
 'user2 5',
 'user3 4',
 'user3 2',
 'user3 1']
In [269]: [(i,x) for i,j in zip(ul,ll) for x in j]
Out[269]: 
[('user1', 1),
 ('user1', 2),
 ('user1', 3),
 ('user2', 3),
 ('user2', 4),
 ('user2', 5),
 ('user3', 4),
 ('user3', 2),
 ('user3', 1)]

In [272]: list(zip(ul,ll))
Out[272]: [('user1', [1, 2, 3]), ('user2', [3, 4, 5]), ('user3', [4, 2, 1])]
```

`zip(list1,list2)` is a handy way of pairing items in lists, and even 'transposing' lists.  'Transpose' in this context is purely an analogy, since lists, and pairs of lists don't really have columns and rows.

Answer (score 1):

a = [['Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3'],['Value3', 'Value4', 'Value5'],['Value4', 'Value2', 'Value1']]

```
for i,each in enumerate(a):
    for elem in each:
        print "user%s" %(i+1),elem
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy.transpose to transpose an array which is rectangular.

```
numpy.transpose([[ 0,1],[2,3]]) 
array([[0, 2],
       [1, 3]])
```

the result is a numpy.ndarray but you can use `.tolist()` to convert back to a list.

This is not a super fast use of the transpose function and for larger projects you should probably write something better, but if you are just looking for something simple to include in your tutorial then it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the response but this won't work for my requirement. This can work if I have value in following structure: [[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[1,3],[1,5]...] .

Comment: After looking at some of the other answers, and re-reading your question, it appears that you don't want the transpose at all. Adding the extra `userN` column means you are just looking for some fancy printing. I'd recommend updating/editing your question to reflect this.

@hpaulj 's answer above seems to be the best option in my mind.